# How to update the payload from the dev tools in my feature file

Tags: karate

i see this below in my chrome Dev tools

[Dev Tool Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wjAZ.jpg)

in feature file i added my payload like this-dont think this is the right syntax (Copied directly from the Pay Load )

- def planstocomparepayload  =
  """
  {

  ```
  "idObject" : {configurationCode: "HDHP_PPO_4000_622c2d0b822ebf256750737de8e706cff77530c8"} ,

  "configurationCode" : "HDHP_PPO_4000_622c2d0b822ebf256750737de8e706cff77530c8" ,

  "planIdObjects" : [{configurationCode: "HDHP_PPO_2000_b2061f8c0d8d4991114eb463522ce5681532046f"},…] ,

  "0": {configurationCode: "HDHP_PPO_2000_b2061f8c0d8d4991114eb463522ce5681532046f"},

  "configurationCode": "HDHP_PPO_2000_b2061f8c0d8d4991114eb463522ce5681532046f",

   "1": {configurationCode: "HDHP_PPO_4000_622c2d0b822ebf256750737de8e706cff77530c8"},

   "configurationCode": "HDHP_PPO_4000_622c2d0b822ebf256750737de8e706cff77530c8"
  ```

}
"""
Need help

Comment: no sorry, I pass on this question. take some time to read the docs. or try to export a cURL command - and maybe that will get us somewhere